# Hidden Illustrator layers

Tags: layers

I cannot find what I believe are hidden layers in a piece I am doing in Illustrator.  Can someone please tell me how I might find layers that are hidden?

Answer (score 3):

If it is a layer that has been hidden, you can toggle it's visibility in the layers pallet by clicking on the eyeball.

[image]

If it is one object in a layer that is hidden you can use the shortcut <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> this will call Object -> Show All.

Answer (score 1):

Some objects can be invisible if they are masked. If this a case you should find the mask and Hide it in turn - this will reveal all objects hidden by mask. You can change these objects and return the mask's visibility after that...

Sometimes, you can find hidden objects by clicking Object->Show All...